# JQuery Mobile site causing odd URL outcomes

Tags: jquery, url, mobile

I am working on a JQuery Mobile site generated through Dreamweaver using one of their templates.  On the main index page, I have some pages going to subindexes, and I have several direct URLs.

Here are two URLs in the list:

```
<li><a href="./about-morningside-recovery/">Learn More About Us</a></li>    <!-- page redirect -->
<li><a href="./morningside-staff/">Meet Our Staff</a></li>                  <!-- page redirect -->
```

The first one, when clicked on the actual site

```
http://www.morningsiderecovery.com/mobile-05-08-12/
```

leads to the proper destination

```
http://www.morningsiderecovery.com/mobile-05-08-12/about-morningside-recovery/
```

The second one, when clicked on, leads to the following bogus url, which won't resolve and sends me to the default home page:

```
http://www.morningsiderecovery.com/mobile-05-08-12/#/mobile-05-08-12/morningside-staff/
```

I'm getting the exact same behavior in IE, Chrome, and Firefox (PC) and Safari (both Mac and iPhone versions).

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening, and how I can make it stop?  This one's got me completely perplexed.

Thanks so much,

Jim Y.

Comment: try to remove point at `href` -> `href="/about-morningside-recovery/"`